# Drupal 6: add webform to node or embed into a node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've been using the webform module for a while, but now I'll need a solution that is easy for a webmaster to use, so no php.

Perhaps, when they are creating a node they can add a webform without have to get into the template files to add a block or something.

Just looking for some suggestions.

Comment: A webform *is* a node, why do you need to attach it to another node? Why not just use it as a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webform provides a node itself , if you want to customize the look n feel, the enable devel, theme developer modules and get the proper name for tpl file and customize.

And if you want form only, then  use
    drupal_get_form('webform_id');
This will return complete html for your form.

Comment: drupal_get_form is what I need, so I can add a form to any page easily.